# With QAbstractListModel, is it necessary to implement insertRows and removeRows if the model is resizable?

Tags: c++, qt, qabstractitemmodel, qabstractlistmodel

I'm implementing a `QAbstractListModel`-derived class (though this question can apply to `QAbstractItemModel` as well) that will be a `QListView`'s model. The list view is intended to be a log with a maximum number of items that it can display. So it has the following properties:

- The items are not editable
- They can't be dragged, dropped, or otherwise reordered
- Rows are added and removed by a process not driven by user action (i.e. there's a new item to log)

Basically, my model will have something akin to an `appendItem(const MyDataType &val)` function, and depending on the number of items in the list, appending an item might remove an item from the top of the list.

In this case, is it necessary to reimplement `insertRows()` and `removeRows()` from `QAbstractListModel`? These functions seem ill-suited for what I'm doing anyway, because `insertRows()` does *not* specify what data is being added, and yet I need to make a change to my model's underlying data structure to add an item. That only makes sense to do if I have actual data to add.

Can I just write a function like `appendItem(const MyDataType &val)` that internally calls `beginInsertRows`, `endInsertRows`, and if necessary, `beginRemoveRows` and `endRemoveRows`, and not bother with `insertRows` and `removeRows`? Or is that using `QAbstractItemModel` incorrectly and will cause errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `appendItem(...)` approach is valid.
It is exactly akin to `void QStandardItemModel::appendRow(const QList<QStandardItem *> &items)` which is nothing more than a method created by the Qt developers themselves solely to make life easier. If it is something they do, why not you?

Note that as soon as you make your model writable from a view, you need to override all these pesky methods from `QAbstractItemView` but even in that case, you are free to keep `appendItem(...)` as a convenience method.